# Accumulation points, Topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

Show that if $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space and for each $x \in \overline{A}, {\left\lbrace x \right\rbrace}'$ is closed, then $A'$ is closed.

I know $\overline{A} = A \cup A'$. So $\overline{A} = \cup_{x \in A} {\left\lbrace x \right\rbrace} \bigcup \cup_{x \in A'} {\left\lbrace x \right\rbrace}$

Also $y \in {\left\lbrace x \right\rbrace}' \longleftrightarrow$ for each $E \in E_y, E \cap ({\left\lbrace x \right\rbrace}-{\left\lbrace y \right\rbrace}) \neq \emptyset$ 
And $X-{\left\lbrace x \right\rbrace}' \in \tau$, so every $E$ in which $y \in E$ and $X-{\left\lbrace x \right\rbrace}' \subseteq E$; then $E \in E_y$. Please help

Comment: what is $E_y$? It is difficult to follow what you are saying in the last paragraph. Are you saying that each $X-\{x\}'$ is open (and hence each $\{x\}'$ closed), how would that relate to the first paragraph (perhaps concluding that $A'$ is closed without any extra assumptions)?

Comment: E_y is the set that contains all sets that are neighborhood of y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So suppose $\{x\}'$ is closed for all $x \in X$.

Let's try to prove $A'$ is closed. So let $x \notin A'$, and we need to find an open set $O_x$ that contains $x$, and is disjoint from $A'$.
First note that $x \notin A'$ implies that there is an open neighbourhood $U_x$ of $x$ such that $U_x \cap (A\setminus\{x\})  =\emptyset$, i.e. $U_x \cap A= \emptyset$ or $U_x \cap A = \{x\}$, or $U_x \cap a \subseteq \{x\}$.

Also, by definition $x \notin \{x\}'$, so $X\setminus \{x\}'$ is open and contains $x$. Now define $O_x = U_x \cap (X\setminus \{x\}')$, which is an open neighbourhood of $x$.

Let $p \in O_x$. Suppose $p \in A'$. This would mean that 
$O_x$, as an open neighbourhood of $p$, intersects $A$ in a point $a \neq p$. As $a \in O_x \cap A \subseteq U_x \cap A \subseteq \{x\}$ we have $a=x$, but 
$p \in O_x \subseteq X\setminus\{x\}' $, hence $p \notin \{x\}'$ so there is an open neighbourhood $V_p$ of  $p$ that does not contain $x$ at all. But then $p \in V_p \cap O_x$ misses $A$ entirely, so $p \notin A'$.

This shows, as required, that $O_x \cap A' = \emptyset$ and $A'$ is closed.

Comment: You say Ox intersected with X \ the accumulation points of {p} intersects A In a point a different of p. How do you know a is different of p if p doesn't belong to the accumulation points of {p}?

Comment: @MihaelArceBaldo $O_x$(or any open set containing $p$) intersecting $A$ in point different from $p$, is what the definition of $p \in A'$ (what I assumed for a contradiction) is.

Comment: You are right, but at the end you put X\ the accumulation points of {x} doesn't contain x, but x is in that set because x isn't inside {x}'

Comment: @MihaelArceBaldo But $p$ is in that set as well (it's in $O_x$ after all). That's why we have the contradiction.. We get strange things because we are in an impossible situation (which is what proofs from contradiction need to do).

Comment: And why is a contradiction that p is in Ox? Remember p is not in A, is in A'. So p is not in Ox intersected with A, so p is not in {x}. Sorry, I don't see the contradiction. I see you have proved that if p is in A', then p is not in A

Comment: @MihaelArceBaldo see edit at the end. I needed one more explicitation.

Comment: Thanks!! I thought this was imposible! Now I undertood it, really thankyou.

Comment: @MihaelArceBaldo you're welcome.

Comment: Don't you want to do another one?

Comment: You posted an almost identical question earlier. You mean that one? @MihaelArceBaldo

Comment: Yes, of accumilation points too. When you solve this problems you visualize the sets and the points in your mind? When I can I do that but when there are too much cases is difficult for me because I can't keep on mind the image of one case while thinking in another one.